# Convert HTML div content to json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I currently have the following HTML...

```
<div id="tabs-1" class="tabs-1 ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-droppable" aria-labelledby="layoutName" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" style="z-index: auto;">

    <div id="mosami1" class="mosami ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging inside-drop-zone highlight "  style="position: absolute; left: 38.4735%; top: 78.1949%; width: 19.3344%; z-index: 100;">
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: auto; margin-left: 119.583px;"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: auto; margin-left: 119.583px;"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: auto;"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: auto;"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: auto;"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: auto;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

... That I would like to turn into JSON as follows:

```
{
    "divID": {
        "options": {
            "id": "tabs-1",
            "class": "tabs-1 ui-tabs-panel ....",
            "z-index": "auto",
        }
        "div": {
            "options": {
                "id":"mosami1",
                "class": "mosami ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging"
                "z-index": "100",
                "left": "38.47"
            },
        },
        "div1": {
            "class": "ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n"
            "z-index": "auto"
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

I am trying to do this using JQuery, but the nesting makes things complex.

Please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use a recursive function that takes in a jQuery node and returns a javascript object representing the data of that node.  Parse out the options for the passed in node, then iterate over the children of the jQuery node calling the recursive function.  Something like this:

```
var parse = function($el) {
  var result = {};

  result.options = {
    // parse $el for properties
  };

  $el.children().each(function(i, e) {
    result[$(this).prop('tagName') + i] = parse($(this));
  })

  return result;
}
```